# I am looking to find the etiolology of <!doctype> language.?

Tags: html

Since the doctype is not the main root element of an HTML page then the question I have is what language is the !doctype?

Answer (score 1):

The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is a **self-contained instruction** which tells the user agent (usually by reference) what type of markup (SGML / XML / HTML etc.) and what version of markup a document is written in.

**Further reading:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration

Answer (score 0):

I think w3schools puts it pretty good:
`In HTML 4.01, the <!DOCTYPE> declaration refers to a DTD, because HTML 4.01 was based on SGML. The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp